# Can we add co author later?

Tags: publications, research-process, engineering, science

Me and my friends did a project during final semester. It got accepted for publication. Later I came to abroad for studies. My friends didn’t add my name as a co author.I have given my input and it’s my project idea to initiate. Can we add my name as a co author later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding co-authors after acceptance](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/adding-co-authors-after-acceptance)

Comment: @cag51 I don't think this is an exact duplicate: the listed question asks about a a deliberate strategy of omitting authors until after acceptance. In this question the paper has already been accepted, and the omitted author wants to know how to fix the issue.

Comment: @cag51 I think avid is correct. The two questions are different. I retracted my dup vote.

Comment: If your name isn't added, then the manuscript plagiarizes your work.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, it is possible to make changes up until the point that final proofs have been submitted. However, at a well-run journal any attempt to add an author after acceptance would require approval from the journal's editor, and they would likely require an explanation for why this change is being sought before agreeing.

The reason for this is to guard against various forms of misconduct, especially:

- subversion of the review process, e.g. by concealing conflicts of interest;
- offers of authorship as a reward/bribe.

If the editor is satisfied with your explanation, they will allow you to add authors. If they are not, the result is likely to be that the paper's acceptance is rescinded, and it is rejected from the journal. Note that many journals require the corresponding author to certify that they have included all relevant individuals as authors as part of the submission process, and admitting that you lied here does not do much for your credibility.

Comment: AIUI, OP is not the corresponding author, so the "you" in "you lied" may not be appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

I believe we cannot. This is because the purpose of an article is to be a source of information and entertainment for people who do not have the time to do research on their own, which means that it must be as accurate as possible.
If you were to go back and change things after it was published, then what are the readers supposed to believe?

The co-author would likely have a different perspective than the original author, which means that he would either disagree with it or expand on the topic in ways that could be considered offensive by people who agree with the original article.

It is possible that the co-author would disagree with the topic and remove it entirely, which makes a mockery of the entire article.

It is also possible that the co-author might add information that was not there before, which would change the focus of the article and make it more about him or her than he main topic.

I believe it is best to keep articles like this as they are, where the author has a single point of view that will not change over time.